# the views.py is not fetching the value from the input box in the template

Tags: python, django

When I run the following code, it is showing a DoesNotExist error at 'post_connected'.

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from users.models import profile
from .models import Follow, post, like_post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def home(request):
    user = request.user
    info = profile.objects.get(user=user)
    follow1 = Follow.objects.filter(follow_user=user)
    follow2 = Follow.objects.filter(user=user)
    follow_by = follow1.count()
    follow_to = follow2.count()

    follows = [user]
    for obj in follow2:
        follows.append(obj.follow_user)
    posts = post.objects.filter(author__in=follows).order_by('-date')

    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    count = posts.count()

    postid = request.POST.get('post_id')
    post_connected = post.objects.get(id=postid)
    mypost = like_post.objects.filter(user=user, liked=post_connected)
    if mypost.exists():
        liked = False
    else:
        liked = True

    context = {
        'user':user, 
        'liked':liked,
        'post':posts,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'follow_by':follow_by,
        'follow_to':follow_to,
        }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

now, this is my template view

```
{% for posts in page_obj %}
    <div class="posts">
    <img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" style="width: 17px; height:14px;"> 
    <a href="/users/user/{{posts.author}}/" class="username" style="font-size:18px;">{{posts.author}}</a><br><br>
    <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:17px;">{{posts.content}}</span><br><br>
    <form action="/like/{{posts.id}}/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" value="{{posts.id}}" name="post_id" style="display: none;">

    <button style="background-color: inherit; border:none; outline:none">
        {% if liked %}
        <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i>
        {% else %}
        <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: lightgrey;"></i>
        {% endif %}
    </button>
    <span style="font-size:12px; float:right"><b>Posted on:</b> {{posts.date | date:"H:i D, d M"}}</span>
    </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
```

I think that the server is not able to fetch the value from the input box. I don't know what have i done wrong. Please help me. Thanku

Comment: What error is being displayed?

Comment: @Redvelvetpastry it is showing a DoesNotExist error

Comment: What is 'post_connected' in your project?

Comment: You could try checking if everything is spelled right and it does exist in your code, and the code is saved and then run.

Comment: @Redvelvetpastry 'post_connected' is the variable in my views.py file used for a get object.

Comment: @Redvelvetpastry I've already checked all the spellings

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the line

```
post_connected = post.objects.get(id=postid)
```

That you have a model named post. Make sure the model has been imported to views.py and the model has been migrated before running the code.

If that is done, make sure the .get() is being used to call an entry that exists. According to the documentation,

> If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a
> DoesNotExist exception. This exception is an attribute of the model
> class that the query is being performed on.

Comment: I have impported the model and migrated it also. after that only it is howing an error

Comment: Could you add the directory structure and the statement where the model was imported?

Comment: Done. You can see it

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you provide the answer too

Answer (score 0):

There were many input boxes with the same id as the input box was inside the for loop. Hence, it was getting multiple values and nothing was happening.